# How can i get the http status in eclipse swt Browser?

Tags: java, browser, swt

I've been working on a bit of `Java` code  which needs to handle an `HTTP`  authentication using `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser`.
I need to get http status:

> HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)/403 (Forbidden)).

The code in question uses `org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE` via the SWT browser and unfortunately I've discovered that you cannot get http event!

The event is handled inside `IE.java` (SWT source)  without giving you the opportunity to do something useful (like get the HTTP status code). 
I could use an additional connection using `HttpURLConnection` and `Authenticator.setDefault()` / `getPasswordAuthentication()` - which is wasteful as I don't want to make two connections to the webserver...

It's not even as if you can derive a new class from org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE because the required member variables have default visibility which means anything outside the `org.eclipse.swt.browser` package can't access them.

How can I get the http status in swt Browser ?

Comment: Have you tried adding an AuthenticationListener?

Comment: You can't use `HttpURLConnection` or any other HTTP code of the JDK to help to authenticate requests. The HTTP connection is made through the native browser component (IE in your case, Mozilla or WebKit on other platforms/configurations) and its own session management, separate from the JDK HTTP session management.

Comment: Yes i tried .AuthenticationListener  doesn't get status FORBIDEN

Comment: I'd still be interested in an answer to how to get the HTTP status code - so that the Java code can then set an alternative URL for the browser if for example the preferred file is not found (environment happens to be Windows/IE11)  At the risk of moaning - I expected browser control to have a 'get' method to return it!  I'd be willing to parse the HTML response if that were exposed.  Given the range of listeners that are available I don't really understand the idea behind leaving out what I would have thought were more basic features.